# Presenting a ViewController from within a CollectionViewCell that is nested in a TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, presentviewcontroller

How can I present a ViewController from within a CollectionViewCell that is nested in a TableViewCell and that TableViewCell is inside a ViewController?

I have tried `presentViewController` and `performSegue` but they can't be called from within a cell.

Detailed explanation:

I have three files.

1. ProfileViewController
2. PeopleCategoryTableViewCell
3. PeopleCategoryCollectionViewCell

When someone taps on a story in CollectionViewCell then I want them to redirect to another ViewController i.e. SinglePostVC()

What I have tried:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("inside this")
    self.window?.rootViewController?.present(SinglePostVC(), animated: true, completion: nil)
    print("outside this")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use protocol and delegate like this

In `tableViewCell`

```
protocol CellDelegate {
    func colCategorySelected(_ indexPath : IndexPath)
}
```

var delegate : CellDelegate?

In didSelect

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    delegate?.colCategorySelected(indexPath)
}
```

In your ProfileViewController

```
class HomeVC: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, CellDelegate{
:
:

func colCategorySelected(_ indexPath : IndexPath){
    // Push here
  }
:
:
}
```

And dont forget

`cellForRow`

```
   let Cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! tableCell

     Cell.delegate = self // dont forget this line.
     return Cell
```

Comment: giving error in step 2. 

use of unresolved identifier 'delegate'

Comment: cannot declare cell.delegate=self i.e. the last step 

Error - Cannot assign value of type ProfileViewController to type CellDelegate

Comment: You will need to create the protocol, then create a variable in your `ProfileViewController` called 'delegate' `var delegate : CellDelegate?` to hold the reference.  Then you can assign your cell's delegate to be that variable.  If you are not familiar with the protocol - delegate pattern I would really suggest you look into and learn it completely.  It is used all over the place with Cocoa/iOS programming.

Comment: Also make sure your `ProfileViewController` subscribes to the `CellDelegate` : `Class ProfileViewController : UIViewController, CellDelegate`

Comment: thanks. its running now but the vc that i am redirecting it too is showing error on this line - singlePostTable.dataSource = self
        singlePostTable.delegate = self ... "unexpected found nil while unwrapping an optional"

Answer (score 0):

You can emit notification from PeopleCategoryCollectionViewCell and listen on it in ProfileViewController, then you can normally present view controller.

Tutorial for local notifications: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/local-notifications-with-ios-10/

Example:

```
NSNotificationCenter
        .defaultCenter()
        .postNotificationName(kCellTappedKey, object: nil, userInfo: nil)
```

And listen:

```
notificationCenter.addObserver(self,
                                   selector: #selector(self.onCellTapped(_:)),
                                   name: kDocumentCellTappedKey,
                                   object: nil)
```

And add this function:

```
func onCellTapped(notification: NSNotification) { //call perform segue }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer .. can you please show me the code . I am a newbie and m stuck in it for hours .